# Bash - Adapting script to rename files with numbers

Tags: bash, file, numbers, sh, rename

I have this script

```
rename_files() {
  title="${1##*${2} - }"
  for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
    case "${filename##*.}" in
      ext1|ext2|ext3)
        mkdir "/User/Downloaded/${title}"
        new_path="/User/Downloaded/${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
        echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
        mv "$filename" "$new_path"
        ;;
    esac
  done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "/User/Downloads/${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category CAT1
rename_category CAT2
```

That do this

Before

```
.
├── Downloads
│   ├── CAT1 - Something ── File.ext1
│   └── CAT2 - SomethingElse ── OtherFile.ext1
├── Downloaded
    ├── CAT1
    ├── CAT2
```

After

```
.
├── Downloads
│   ├── CAT1 - Something
│   └── CAT2 - SomethingElse
├── Downloaded
    ├── CAT1 ──  Something ── Something.ext1
    ├── CAT2 ──  SomethingElse ── SomethingElse.ext1
```

What I'm trying to do is that if only there's more that one file with the same extension, then these files will be renamed adding `_1`, etc.

Before

```
.
├── Downloads
│   ├── CAT1 - Something ├── File.ext1
                         ├── ExampleFile.ext1
│   └── CAT2 - SomethingElse ── OtherFile.ext1
├── Downloaded
    ├── CAT1
    ├── CAT2
```

After

```
.
├── Downloads
│   ├── CAT1 - Something
│   └── CAT2 - SomethingElse
├── Downloaded
    ├── CAT1 ──  Something ── Something_1.ext1
                           ── Something_2.ext1
    ├── CAT2 ──  SomethingElse ── SomethingElse.ext1
```

**EDIT**:

```
#!/bin/bash

rename_files() {
   title="${1##*${2} - }"
   for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
   case "${filename##*.}" in
     doc|ext|ext)
       mkdir "/User/Downloaded/${title}"
       new_path="/User/Downloaded/${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
       let "iters=1"
       while [ -f $new_path ] ; do
          $new_path=$new_path"$iters"
          let "iters++"
       done
       echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
       mv "$filename" "$new_path"
       ;;
   esac
   done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "/User/Downloads/${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category CAT1
```

**EDIT2:**

There are two `.doc` files in `/User/Downloads/DOC - TEST`

```
/User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc
                          /Sample-doc-file-200kb.doc
```

What I want is

```
/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST_1.doc
                     /TEST_2.doc
```

This is the output log

```
chmod +x /User/TEST.sh
sh /User/TEST.sh
moving /User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc -> /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc
mkdir: /User/Downloaded/TEST: File exists
/User/TEST.sh: line 12: /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc=/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc1: No such file or directory
/User/TEST.sh: line 12: /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc=/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc2: No such file or directory
```

etc.

**Updated output log**

```
sh /User/Script.sh 
moving /User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc -> /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc
mv: rename {/User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc} to {/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc}: No such file or directory
mkdir: /User/Downloaded/TEST: File exists
moving /User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-200kb.doc -> /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc
mv: rename {/User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-200kb.doc} to {/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc}: No such file or directory
```

**OUTPUT UPDATED**:

Here is my initial situation

```
User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/SampleDoc.doc
                         /OtherSampleDoc.doc
                         /OtherDoc.doc

User/Downloaded/
```

After the script I only obtain

```
User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/OtherSampleDoc.doc
                         /OtherDoc.doc

User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc
```

But want I want would be

```
User/Downloads/DOC - TEST

User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST_1.doc
                    /TEST_2.doc
                    /TEST_3.doc
```

And this is the output

```
sh /User/Script.sh 
moving /User/Downloads/DOC - TEST/OtherDoc.doc -> /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc
mkdir: /User/Downloaded/TEST: File exists
/User/Script.sh: line 12: /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc=/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc1: No such file or directory
/User/Script.sh: line 12: /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc=/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc2: No such file or directory
/User/Script.sh: line 12: /User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc=/User/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc3: No such file or directory
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rename_files() {
   title="${1##*${2} - }"
   for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
   case "${filename##*.}" in
     ext1|ext2|ext3)
       mkdir "/User/Downloaded/${title}"
       new_path="/User/Downloaded/${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
       let "iters=1"
       while [ -f $new_path ] ; do
          new_path=$new_path"$iters"
          let "iters++"
       done
       echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
       mv "${filename}" "${new_path}"
       ;;
   esac
   done
}
```

Comment: I updated the script - see **EDIT** - but what I obtain is folder in which I can not enter nor copy/delete. May you please help me?

Comment: It's probably because of the spaces in the folder name. Change the mv statement to `mv "${filename}" "${new_path}"`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Tested the updated script but it doesn't work; see the new updated log. I do not understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a silly error. `{$filename}` should have been `${filename}`, not sure how I messed that up... oops! I've updated the answer.

Comment: There's something wrong; the script doesn't find the files and it continues to run. See last **OUTPUT UPDATED**

Comment: @DylanDog, There was another silly error. `$new_path=$new_path"$iters"` should have been `new_path=$new_path"$iters"`. I have corrected the script, but I suggest you learn to do this yourself -- http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/ appears to be a reasonable guide.

Comment: Thank you very much: I'll look at that guide; it is really useful! Only last thing: what I obtain now is `TEST.doc`, `TEST.doc1`, `TEST.doc12`, `TEST.doc123`, etc. Is it possible to keep only the last number (1, 2,3 ,etc.) and move it before the extension like this `TEST1.doc`?

Comment: It is possible, but you'd have to use awk, pearl, cut, or sed to munge the number into the string exactly where you want it. In the case of a file without an extension, you want it at the end, but in the case of a file with an extension, you want it just before the extension. It's not super straightforward, because if you code something that inserts the digit before the last ".", you'll end up with the digit in the middle of the filename if your file has no extension, but contains a ".", so to do it properly, you need to use a list of all extensions you expect to receive.